# rewrites path on ingress kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i have tomcat backend service running on kubernetes cluster try  to rewrite using ingress with path /blob/api/v1/test-backend > /api/v1/test-backend so
the configuration now is running so can hit to xx.somedomain.com/blob/api/v1/test-backend and i want change to xx.somedomain.com/api/v1/test-backend with rewrites

my basic ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-blob
  namespace: blob-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xx.somedomain.com
    secretName: cert-key
  rules:
  - host: xx.somedomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blob/
        backend:
          serviceName: blob-service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 80
```

and this is yaml for rewrite /blob/

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-blob
  namespace: blob-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xx.somedomain.com
    secretName: cert-key
  rules:
  - host: xx.somedomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blob/api/v1/some-backend
        backend:
          serviceName: blob-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

when i test with api tester like talend is got 405 error

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

```
rewrite.bar.com/something rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/ rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/new rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/new
```

Refer : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: if i do this all the backend is 404

Comment: hope you have updated the host path name service name as per your usecase. if you can share the yaml file that you applied.

Comment: i edited my question sir is that yaml i use for my testing

Comment: 405 is method not allowed.your domain is register in DNS ?

Comment: my subdomain is register in aws route53, i'm using ingress nginx on the gcp as LB then on the route53 i put the ip from ingress-nginx

Comment: i think 405 method is alowed because  i can hit xx.somedomain.com/blob/api/test-backend

Answer (score 0):

Try adding annotation like this
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"

Comment: Can you share the error by hitting the url

Comment: [25/Aug/2021:05:55:15 +0000] "POST /api/v1/test-backend HTTP/2.0" 404